# HTML - input current date and time in link

Tags: html, date, hyperlink

I have the following code for a link in html:

```
<a href="http://earth.nullschool.net/#2015/01/24/1200Z/wind/isobaric/500hPa/">500 mb Earth Wind Map</a>
```

My question is, is there a way to automate the date in the link. I.e. I would like html code that puts the current year, month, and day into the link?

Comment: There is no “current date” concept in HTML. You can get current data in client-side JavaScript or in server-side code, but they relate to different meanings for “current date”. So you cannot have it in HTML, and you need to specify whether you want client-side or server-side date and which technologies are then avalable. (And as you get there, the answers can probably be easily found in relevant tutorials or manuals.)

Answer (score 1):

Thats not Possibile with HTML, but you can easily do it with PHP.

PHP provides a `date()` Function => http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php
It would be something like

```
<a href="http://earth.nullschool.net/#<?php echo date('Y/m/d')?>/1200Z/wind/isobaric/500hPa/">
```

Parameter 1 of the Date-Function allows you to format your code. In this case you want to have Year followed by month and day seperated by `/`. You can add a 2. Parameter with a Timestamp, but it normaly just uses the current Date and Time.

The `echo` Outputs the code.

(If you use PHP in youre Code you have to rename your fle to `.php`)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Javascript's [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

```
var d = new Date();
var year = d.getFullYear();
var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
var day = d.getDate();

document.getElementById("link").href = "http://earth.nullschool.net/#" + year + "/" + month + "/" + day + "/1200Z/wind/isobaric/500hPa/";
```

with HTML code as

```
<a href="http://earth.nullschool.net/#2012/01/24/1200Z/wind/isobaric/500hPa/" id="link">500 mb Earth Wind Map</a>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/lexingtonpenguins/71eggyu6/)

Comment: I can't recommend you to use Javascript, becouse ist Client-Side, therefore you don't know if ist enabeld and also it uses the Client Time (Wich can be wrong an often is it)

Comment: I tried to decode your username but it's not divisible by 4.

Comment: @j_s_stack, good point. Personally, I would suggest using PHP.

Comment: from where i see it, people disabling javascript just don't deserve you care about them. And most probably if people want something time-related, they want it related to their time, not to server-time which you don't even know what it is as a client...